# Is it correct proof of "if $f$ is continuous then $f$ is integrable"?

Tags: calculus

Hypothesis : if $f(x)$ is continuous in [a, b], then $f(x)$ is integrable in [a,b].
Proof :

1. Let $f(x)$ isn't integrable in [a,b].
2. Then, $F(x) = $$\int_a^x f(t)dt$$ $ doesn't exist.
3. Then, $F'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \int_x^{x+h} f(t)dt/h$ doesn't exist.
4. Then, $\lim_{h \to 0}\lim_{n \to \infty} (\sum_{i=1 \to n}f(x+ih/n))/n$ doesn't exist.
5. $f(x)$ is continuous, so $\lim_{h \to 0}f(x+ih/n) = f(x)$
6. $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x) = f(x)$ exist in [a,b]. (Contradiction)
7. Thus, Hypothesis is true.

Comment: You can’t necessarily pass the limit as $h\to0$ all the way through into $f(x+ih/n)$. Or at least, in order to do that there is you need to prove first that you can

Comment: I'm not pass limit as $h -> 0$ into $f(x +ih/n)$. I use $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I mean, exchanging the limit of $h$ with the limit of the sum might be possible here, but I was just noting it isn’t necessarily possible

Comment: Can you tell me when exchaning the limit of h with the limit of the sum is impossible? I think if each $\lim_{h \to 0} f(x + ih/n)$  exists, then exchangin is possible.

Comment: See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) which tells you when it *is* possible. I’m sure there are a myriad other theorems on the topic - this is the only one I know. And I expect that you’re correct by the way; $f(x+ih/n)$ should be a bounded function and your proof works anyway

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer!! I study more...

Comment: Comments: (i) There are missing quantifiers; for example, 2. should read "There exists an $x_0$ such that if $x > x_0$, then ..."; (ii) When we write $\lim(g, x_0)$, there is a presumption that $g$ is defined near $x_0$, which is not the case in 3.; (iii) 3. does not imply 4. (Think of the Dirichlet function on $[0, 1]$: not integrable, but the evenly-sampled Riemann sums are all $0$.) One might object, "This counterexample cannot arise if $f$ is continuous!" Ah, but that's nearly what we're trying to prove. <> I haven't carefully read further.

Comment: Like this? 2. $\forall x \in [a,b]. g(x) = \int_a^xf(t)dt$ doesn't exist.  
In case 3, I think because $g(x)$ doesn't exist, so, 3. can't exist in any case.  Is it incorrect?